# Any easy ways to automate, copying cookies from API calls as a pre-requisite for running shell script based API calls

Tags: shell, curl, session-cookies

The way out automation setup works is,

1. Make a UI based(having a web endpoint) API invocation with a random input, and get/copy the auth cookies from the call
2. Set these cookies in Mac/Terminal using CURL command, export CURL_blah_blah command
3. Execute shell scripts that uses the cookies we set of the respective services to perform service to service tests

While the current setup works perfectly fine, there's a painpoint with this approach, where auth cookies expire every 20 mins, which is forcing us to run #1 and #2, every 20 mins, before running #3.  Appreciate if there are ways to simplify #1 and #2 steps. And, let me know if additional details are needed.